# Why can't xmlrpc client append item to list accessable via xmlrpc server procedure?

Tags: python, xml-rpc, simplexmlrpcserver, xmlrpcclient

Server code (based on Python library reference):

```
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCServer
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler

class RequestHandler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):
    rpc_paths = ()

server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("127.0.0.1", 8000),
                            requestHandler=RequestHandler)
server.register_introspection_functions()

l = list()

def say_hi():
    return 'hi !'

def append(event):
    l.append(event)

server.register_function(say_hi)
server.register_function(append)

server.serve_forever()
```

Client (interpreter started from another terminal window):

```
>>> from xmlrpc.client import ServerProxy
>>> s = ServerProxy('http://127.0.0.1', allow_none=True)
>>> s.say_hi()
'hi !'
>>> s.append(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
xmlrpc.client.Fault(Fault 1: "<class 'TypeError'>:cannot
                    marshal None unless allow_none is enabled")
```

How do I fix this? Am I using xmlrpc improperly?

Comment: For others who also found this issue, I found that while server was down and client send requests to the server, results in cannot marshal None unless allow_none is enabled

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your XMLRPC server is raising a fault since it cannot marshal `None`. You need to add `allow_none=True` to the server constructor:

```
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("127.0.0.1", 8000),
                        requestHandler=RequestHandler, 
                        allow_none=True)
```

Comment: I'd also point out that this `None` comes from the fact that the `append()` function on your server does not return anything; therefore it returns `None`, and when the XMLRPC mechanism tries to marshal that `None` back to the client as a return value, said exception was thrown, instead.